# Storing MD5s and UUIDs efficiently in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I am building an application that will need to store the following data types in an Oracle database:

- MD5 (hashes of files)
- Java-generated UUIDs

Some of the MD5s will be used as keys between various tables, so will be indexed.

Ultimately MD5s and UUIDs represent 128 bit numbers - do I just use the `RAW(16)` type?

I need to be able to get the data back again (including instantiating new instances of Java's `UUID` class from the data in the database).

Answer (score 0):

The options are:

- `CHAR(32)` which takes up 32 bytes on disk, but is human readable
- `RAW(16)` which takes up 16 bytes on disk, but is not human readable

`CHAR(32)` of course will consume double the disk space, but index lookups will be slightly slower too, because there will be less (half) as many entries per index page, so access via an index will be about twice as slow as `RAW(16)`.

Converting either to a `java.util.UUID` is about the same effort, so there's no real difference there.

Unless there is a big advantage to being about to read the values as plain text, I would use `RAW(16)`

Comment: Why `CHAR(32)`? Why could you not use `CHAR(16 BYTE)`?

Comment: You could use a NUMBER to store it as 22 bytes. Would look ugly if displayed.